# Pass custom binding's value to DOM element added in custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I am trying to use knockoutjs custom binding to create a component. This might not be a good idea and if there are other way to do the same thing, I am open to alternatives.

The idea is to set a custom binding to an element so the element content get's filled based on the data passed to the binding.

For example (in jade template), I would write:

```
div(data-bind="keyValueEditor: $data.somePropertyHoldingSomeData")
```

And I have the following (simplified for the question) custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.keyValueEditor = {
    init: function ( element, valueAccessor ) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap( value );

        $( "<span data-bind='text: theDataThatWasPassedToTheBinding.value'/>" ).appendTo( element );
        }
    },
    update: function ( element, valueAccessor ) {
    }
};
```

Here `value` is an observable that I would like to bind to the span content using the `text` binding. My problem is that I don't know what to put in `theDataThatWasPassedToTheBinding` so it equals to `$data.somePropertyHoldingSomeData` that was passed as the binding's value.

I tried:

```
$( "<span data-bind='text: " + valueAccessor().value + "'/>" ).appendTo( element );
```

and

```
$( "<span data-bind='text: " + ko.unwrap( valueAccessor() ).value + "'/>" ).appendTo( element );
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure who -1'd, this is a well-written question. (Care to elaborate, downvoter?)

Comment: Manuel if you get a chance to create it a fiddle it may be easier to help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function
`ko.applyBindingsToNode(node, bindings, viewModel, bindingAttributeName)`

```
ko.bindingHandlers.keyValueEditor = {
    init: function ( element, valueAccessor ) 
    {
        var somePropertyHoldingSomeData = valueAccessor();
        var span = $( "<span>" );
        span.appendTo(element);
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(span[0], {text: somePropertyHoldingSomeData.value})
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MV48E/)